# Trying to get domain SID with GetWindowsAccountDomainSid API fails with error code ERROR_NON_ACCOUNT_SID

Tags: c++, winapi, active-directory, sid

My goal is to see if an arbitrary process runs under certain (non-local, domain) admin accounts. I'm using the following code for that:

```
check_membership(WinAccountDomainAdminsSid);
check_membership(WinAccountEnterpriseAdminsSid);
check_membership(WinAccountCertAdminsSid);
check_membership(WinAccountPolicyAdminsSid);
check_membership(WinAccountSchemaAdminsSid);

void check_membership(WELL_KNOWN_SID_TYPE wellKnownSidType)
{
    //Most error checks are omitted for brevity!

    HANDLE hToken;
    HANDLE hImpToken;
    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
    OpenProcessToken(hProc, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &hToken);
    DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, TOKEN_QUERY, NULL, SecurityImpersonation, TokenImpersonation, &hImpToken);

    DWORD dwcbSize;
    BYTE buffTokenUser[sizeof(TOKEN_USER) + SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE] = {0};
    GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, buffTokenUser, sizeof(buffTokenUser), &dwcbSize);

    BYTE buffDomainSid[SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE] = {0};
    GetWindowsAccountDomainSid(((PTOKEN_USER)buffTokenUser)->User.Sid, buffDomainSid, &dwcbSize);

    BYTE sid[SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE] = {0};
    dwcbSize = sizeof(sid);
    if(CreateWellKnownSid(wellKnownSidType, (PSID)buffDomainSid, sid, &dwcbSize))
    {
        BOOL bIsMember = FALSE;
        if(CheckTokenMembership(hImpToken, &sid, &bIsMember))
        {
            wprintf(L"SidType=%d, Member: %s\n", wellKnownSidType, bIsMember ? L"Yes" : L"No");
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hToken);
    CloseHandle(hImpToken);
    CloseHandle(hProc);
}
```

This works for most processes, but for some `GetWindowsAccountDomainSid` fails with error code `1257`, or `ERROR_NON_ACCOUNT_SID`.

How do I get the domain SID in that case?

Comment: What does a failing SID look like? Similar to the working SIDs but just a different final DWORD or are there other differences?

Comment: @Anders: Yeah, good point. I didn't think to check. Sid for the process may be S-1-5-18 which is Local System, or a service. So what happens with the domain SID in that case?

Comment: These are well known sids, that are the same in every domain. You can't get domain part from this sid. The idea is smart but you cannot solve the problem without providing a domain sid into your function. However, what you can do is get token membership sids and check if any of these groups end with domain admins and other well known rids

Comment: @oldovets: How would I get a token membership sid without having a TCB privilege?

Comment: Also, I'd recommend you to rewrite the method in such a way that openprocess and token functions and will be called only once for a set of groups. Now they are called 5 times (one time for each group)

Comment: @oldovets: Sure. My actual code does exactly that with the handles. I posted it like that here for readability. Still, how'd you get a token membership SID without elevating my process?

Comment: Wrote a simple project, which calls GetTokenInformation with TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS = TokenGroups. However run this program as a Domain Admin. But Local Security Policy (secpol.msc) shows that no user is added to "Act as a part of the operating system" setting. What user is used to run your program\service?

Comment: @oldovets: Standard logged in user. The program takes a PID of a target process that it needs to retrieve information that I've explained in my OP.